# Tracker Domains and TXT records

Tags: validation, pardot, key

I have a problem with the validation key as there is already an entry in the @ record. How can I add the validation key to the already existing record? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DNS records can have multiple TXT entries. For domain validation, simply add a new TXT record.